# Simulating Keystrokes to a Telnet process

Tags: python, bash, automation

On my Linux system I have opened a Telnet session. On the other tab I am running a Python script and giving commands to the Telnet session using mkfifo file redirection. But I am not able to simulate key presses to the Telnet session through my Python script. so in one tab i have opened a telnet session using these commands

```
mkfifo my.fifo
cat >my.fifo &
cat my.fifo | telnet 182.23.45.12 10000 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

Now in another tab i am running a python script which is giving commands to this telnet process. That I am doing through printf "command" > my.fifo .

But I need to send a key press event like up arrow key to the telnet process which i am not able to do using this below command

```
printf "command" > my.fifo
```

I tried using puautogui and xdotool but it did not work

Comment: Any reason you use Python to run shell command, rather than using Bash directly? Also for troubleshooting, take off the telnet pipe and see what the fifo outputs.

Comment: Use https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and for the up arrow, depending on the terminal you want to emulate send something like `\EOA` (see `infocmp | grep kcuu1`)

Comment: @TaylorG. Basically I am doing some text analysis and because of that i have to use python instead of bash.